# Setting the value of a TextField to a Random number

Tags: java, android, random, if-statement

I am writing an Android app that has a `Button` which calls `SelfDestruct()`. There is also a `TextView` which should show `1` or `2`, chosen randomly. However, if it shows `1`, always `1` will be set, same for `2`. It should always create a random number.

This is my code, could someone please help me achieve this...

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

    }
    @Override
    public void SelfDestruct(View View)
    {
        TextView tx= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
        Random r = new Random();
        int x=r.nextInt(2-1) + 1;
        if(x==1)
        {
            tx.setText("1");
        }
        else if(x==2)
        {
            tx.setText("2");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You mean you want it random 1st time then always the same value ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do for you:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

    }
    @Override
    public void SelfDestruct(View View)
    {
        TextView tx= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
        Random r = new Random();
        int x=r.nextInt(2) + 1;  // r.nextInt(2) returns either 0 or 1
        tx.setText(""+x);  // cast integer to String
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the Quick Answer, seems that i just failed with the Random,

Comment: You don't have to do the if-else condition either. Just cast the variable x to a String by appending an empty String in front of it. Java automatic data type promotion will take care of the work for you :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure the problem is in this line:

```
r.nextInt(2-1) + 1;
```

`nextInt(n)` returns a number between 0(inclusive) and n(exclusive). This means you can get any number between 0 and .99 because you passed in 1 as the argument to `nextInt()`. You always get 1 here because any number in the range 0 - .99 + 1 cast to an integer will be 1.

What you actually want numbers in the range of 1 - 2, try this:

```
r.nextInt(2) + 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code, this should work perfectly

```
TextView tx= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
        Random r = new Random();
        int x = r.nextInt(2) % 2 + 1;
        tx.setText("" +x);
```

Comment: you dont event need if else here